# SQL to Linq with SUM, ISNULL, and Left Join : how to make a good linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a problem converting An SQL to LINQ syntax.
This is the Query i have.

```
select ISNULL(Sum(b.Total),0) as 'TotalOP', isnull(Sum(e.Total),0) as 'TotalLPB',  
isnull(Sum(b.Total),0) - isnull(Sum(e.Total),0) as 'Difference'  
from OP a  
left join OP_Detail b on a.ID_Ps_OP = b.ID_Ps_OP  
left join LPB_OP c on a.ID_Ps_OP = c.ID_Ps_OP  
left join LPB d on c.ID_Ps_LPB = d.ID_Ps_LPB and d.ModifyStatus != 'D'  
left join LPBDetail e on d.ID_Ps_LPB = e.ID_Ps_LPB  
where a.ModifyStatus != 'D'
```

The query works well in SQL.

As for information :
 1. OP_Detail contains the goods of the OP. and it has a field named Total which contains the amount of the transaction in OP.
 2. LPB_OP is the connector between LPB and OP.
 3. LPB_Detail contains the goods of the LPB. and it has a field named Total which contains the amount of the transaction in LPB.

Is there any linq syntax that can take these sum, isnull, and left join problem?

Especially the line :
left join LPB d on c.ID_Ps_LPB = d.ID_Ps_LPB and d.ModifyStatus != 'D'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
var lstQuery = 
(from A in OP
from B in OP_Detail
from C in LBP_OP
from D in LPB 
from E in LPBDetail
where 
A.ID_Ps_OP = B.ID_Ps_OP &&
A.ID_Ps_OP = C.ID_Ps_OP &&
((C.ID_Ps_LPB = D.ID_Ps_LPB) && (D.ModifyStatus != 'D')) &&
D.ID_Ps_LPB = E.ID_Ps_LPB
select new
{
A, B, C, D, E
}).ToList();

double dTotalOP = 0;
double dTotalLPB = 0;
double dDifference = 0;

foreach (var record in lstQuery)
{
    dTotalOp += record.B == null ? 0 : record.B.Total;
    dTotalLPM += record.E == null ? 0 : record.E.Total;
    dDifference += dTotalOp - dTotalLPM;
}
```

Comment: You might want to point out that your query would return *all* matched rows to memory, instead of just the three summed values. =)

Comment: And instead of doing the conditional operator logic in the foreach, why not simply set that value when you create your anonymous type? =)

Comment: As for the catch you mention - yeah. I don't think there's a way to create a summation query like that without grouping in the linq query.